# Reading an rss file in c# from a remote web server

Tags: c#, rss

I can read the file rss from the remote web server.

The problem I'm having is reading the contents of the rss file.
I keep getting a error. I know what that is, I just don't know how to fix it.
For some reason it errors out.
here is the error

`Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'xmlRSS' does not exist in the current context`

My code is below.

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Xml;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlsrc = "http://......../News.rss";
            string Password = "myPsw";
            string UserAccount = "myAcc";
            string DomainName = "myDom";
            string xslsrc = "RSS91.xsl";

            if (xmlsrc != "")
            {
                HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlsrc);

                if (UserAccount != "")
                {
                    wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserAccount, Password, DomainName);
                }

                wr.Timeout = 10000;
                WebResponse resp = wr.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                reader.XmlResolver = null;
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                doc.Load(reader);

                xmlRSS.Document = doc;

                }

            xmlRSS.TransformSource = xslsrc;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know what the error is, but we don't know! can you post what error you are receiving?

Comment: the error is: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'xmlRSS' 
does not exist in the current context

Comment: What's the name of your `asp:xml` control on the page? Looks like you copied the sample code from somewhere and didn't name it correctly. It should be `<asp:xml id="xmlRSS" runat="server" />`